# how to remove Duplicate values from Dict in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Hi I just want remove repeated objects should be removed in `dictionary` I am populating it in `tableView`

Here my sample code in 'CellForRowAtIndexPath'

```
controller.titleName = dict["itemName"] as? String
```

**my output:**

```
{
    itemName = test;
},
{
    itemName = funny;
},
    {
    itemName = vv;
},
    {
    itemName = hhh;
},
    {
    itemName = west;
}
```

Comment: Anand please check my answer.It is correct.Check it.

Comment: Anand If my answer is useful for you,please tick and up vote my answer.

Comment: @Anand if you already said " Thanx man its worked " then what was missing in my answer? even you have already accepted my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i think thing you are using array to make dict so before load tableview/collectionview delete all replicated object from your array.

There is one option you have to create `NSSet` from `NSArray` so in NSSet all replicated `object` automatically removed . and then from `NSSet` you have to create `NSArray`.
convert set from array as follow

```
var set = NSSet(array: myarray)
```

To convert array for set

```
var newarry = set.allObjects as NSArray
```

Comment: hey jay both the code i working man thats y i try to mark his answer also

Comment: you can accept only one answer and if you find both are right then you have to choose which one you have to accept and in that case which answer provide first it should be accepted

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
let uniqueArr = Array(Set(dict.values))
```

Comment: Yes, I missed one thine but @Ali Jawed fixed it. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

For your question I have tried separately and I got the answer

```
var arr = [AnyObject]()
var arrAppend = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let array = ["one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three"]
    let uniqueValue = Array(Set(array))
    print("The unique value is - \(uniqueValue)")


    let dictTest = ["itemName":"test"]
    let dictFunny = ["itemName":"funny"]
    let dictVVV = ["itemName":"vvv"]
    let dictHHH = ["itemName":"hhh"]
    let dictWest = ["itemName":"west"]
    let dictTT = ["itemName":"tt"]
    let dictWest1 = ["itemName":"west"]

    arr.append(dictWest1)
    arr.append(dictTest)
    arr.append(dictVVV)
    arr.append(dictTT)
    arr.append(dictWest)
    arr.append(dictFunny)
    arr.append(dictHHH)

    print("Array  Response: \(arr)")

    for keyValue in arr as Array
    {
       let getDictValueFromArray = keyValue["itemName"] as! String
        arrAppend.append(getDictValueFromArray)
    }
    let unique = Array(Set(arrAppend))
    print("the result is-\(unique)")
}
```

The Output for unique is

```
the result is-["funny", "test", "west", "vvv", "hhh", "tt"]
```

Comment: What did i mistake here?Please tell me the reason for down voting my answer.

Comment: Eric If I get the url, I can directly get data from server and I show the response directly.But here it is not possible for getting URL and other things.That is the reason why I created like above.